# How to resolve escaping for variables in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing WordPress theme I have passed the variables but it gives me the recommendation that uses escaping for a variable, so I am not aware of what do these mean and how to solve these error so I need help in these

```
<?php
<p class="site-description"><?php echo $electromart_description;?></p>
?>
```

Error : 
RECOMMENDED: Use escaping for variables

Comment: `<p class="site-description">` is not valid PHP.

Comment: i am getting the error in <?php echo $electromart_description;?> that use escaping of variable so what does these mean exactly

Comment: How do you know that is where the error is? That look perfectly fine. But dumping html in php is not correct. It's on the same line.

Comment: can you guide me what does escaping of variable mean in php

Answer (score 1):

Let me space out the code for you.

```
<?php // open php
    <p class="site-description"> // this is not php
        <?php // open php again
            echo $electromart_description; // perfectly fine php
        ?> // Close second php
    </p> // more html in php
?> // Close the first php
```

See that you have html posted in php without echo?
You need to remove the first PHP tags or echo the html.

This is one option how to solve it:

```
<?php // open php
    echo '<p class="site-description">'; // echo html in php
        <?php // open php again
            echo $electromart_description; // perfectly fine php
        ?> // Close second php
    echo '</p>'; // echoed html in php
?> // Close the first php
```

Comment: but still i dont understand what does escape a variable mean in php

Comment: Most likely the parser believes `class=` is a variable. I can't recreate the issue, I get a unexpected `<` when I try it. https://3v4l.org/b5PfK

Comment: ... why would you leave the second pair of opening/closing PHP tags in your "fixed" code...

Comment: @naththedeveloper There may be other code that OP has not shown us. Maybe OP actually did a **M**VCE.